# Videos being accessible via web and mobile users

Tags: mobile, video

I have to make videos accessible to Blackberry, iPhone and web users. After some initial research I figured that .MP4 seems to be the best format to do this in.

However, my question is: What is the best way to go about resizing videos for each platform? Is it best to provide one standard size for all three platforms? Or should I detect user agents and resize?

Any ideas would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest one size for all mobiles. YouTube videos never fit my iPhone perfectly - but with the iPhone you can scale up to remove the black bars at the side. I'm not sure about formats, but you might want to look at [HTML 5 video](http://diveintohtml5.org/video.html).

For the web, Flash video is still the norm unfortunately, although some browsers support HTML 5.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I ended up using one size to fit all as you suggested.